# KnockoutJS later update

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I want to make HTML markup with GIF progress bar appear when loading a page. Then I use Ajax to get data - fill in the markup and hide the GIF. How do I achieve this behavior with KnockoutJS

```js
var Item = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable();
};

var ItemList = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    var blocks = await get_blocks();
    $.each(blocks, function (index, value) {
        self.list.push(new Item());
    });

      //first, show the HTML-blocks, and then fill them

    $.each(self.list(), async function (index, value) {
        var data = await getData("some-url");
        self.list()[index].name = data.name;
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ItemList());
```

Comment: You want to use a gif.. what if the progress bar fills up before the server responds? Or do you want this kind of GIF? https://giphy.com/gifs/mashable-3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40

Comment: Btw, do you have any code? Right now your question is quite broad. It can be answered in many ways

Comment: @Ray yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: @Ray pseudo-code will add a little later

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```js
var viewModel = function(){
 var self = this;
  self.loadingData = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.callServer = function(){
    self.loadingData(true);
    $.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', function(data){
      console.log(data);
      self.loadingData(false);
    });
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko if: loadingData -->
 <img src="https://i.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.webp">
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: callServer">Call</button>
```

Comment: i added code. Please read the question carefully. I first need to add markup, and then fill it